# Slow down texture changes in an array when dealing with a sprite.

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am making a little game in c# using XNA 4.0. I have successfully made my sprite move in all directions and make it look like it is actually walking using an array.  So far I have only tested this with the "Up" key.  The problem is that when I push the up key, the sprite moves, but it goes through all the elements in the array so fast that it looks like he is running way to fast for the amount of space he is going.  Is there any way to slow down the speed at which the textures change between each other, such as a pause method or something. Any bit of help is appreciated, Thanks.

```
namespace RandomGame
{

    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Color backColor = Color.FromNonPremultiplied(190, 230, 248, 250);
        int i = 0;
        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 500;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }


        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();

        }

        Texture2D[] UpTextures = new Texture2D[6];
        Texture2D startTexture;
        Texture2D leftTexture;
        Texture2D rightTexture;
        Vector2 position = new Vector2(380, 230);

       protected override void LoadContent()
        {


            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            startTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueLinkStart");
            leftTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueLinkLeft");
            rightTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueLinkRight");
            UpTextures[0] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueLinkUp");
            UpTextures[1] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueLinkUp2");
            UpTextures[2] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueLinkUp3");
            UpTextures[3] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueLinkUp4");
            UpTextures[4] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueLinkUp5");
            UpTextures[5] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueLinkUp6");
        }

       protected override void UnloadContent()
        {

        }

       protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            {
                this.Exit();
            }
            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && position.X > -3)
            {
                position.X -= 2;

            }
            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && position.X < 772)
            {
                position.X += 2;
            }
            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && position.Y > -3)
            {
                position.Y -= 2;
            }
            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) && position.Y < 472)
            {
                position.Y += 2;
            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

       protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.FromNonPremultiplied(188, 231, 241, 255));
            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
                spriteBatch.Draw(leftTexture, position, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
                base.Draw(gameTime);
            }
            else if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
                spriteBatch.Draw(rightTexture, position, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
                base.Draw(gameTime);
            }
            else if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {

                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
                spriteBatch.Draw(UpTextures[i], position, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
                i++;
                if (i == 6) { i = 0; }
                base.Draw(gameTime);
            }
            else
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
                spriteBatch.Draw(startTexture, position, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
                base.Draw(gameTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

First of all, you need a variable that holds the animation state. Your `i` is probably supposed to be that. However, you should rename it to e.g. `animationState` to reflect its purpose. Furthermore, it is easier to make it a `float` or `double` variable.

Then updating the animation is a task for the `Update()` method. You obviously rely on the 60 Hz update frequency. This is ok for a small game, but you should take possible slow downs into consideration for bigger ones. If you have `n` sprites, and you want to change the sprite every `m` ms, then you update the `animationState` as follows:

```
animationState += updateDuration * m;
if(animationState >= n) animationState -= n;
```

`updateDuration` is the time since the last update. So for 60 Hz this is `1000.0 / 60`.

And then you need to draw the correct sprite in the `Draw()` method:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(UpTextures[(int)animationState], position, Color.White);
```

Comment: Wont this cause an index out of bounds exception?

Comment: It should not. `animationState` is always `>= 0` and `< n` which should be fine.